# grouping and including files in a php project, by the book

Tags: php

I'm working on my first, rather big project in php. I decided to build everything from scratch, without any framework.

First I had the following structure:

```
index.php
includes/            //all php pages, except index.
includes/scripts/    //all php classes that do not print web pages.
styles/              //all my css files.
images/              //all images used on the website.
```

But this was giving me trouble when including files from within the various folders.

I have now changed it to:

```
index.php
the rest of my .php files
styles/
images/
```

All my includes are working properly now, without having to jump between folders. But I feel like I have lost overview on my project.

At the moment I'm a bit lost on how to do things. What is, by the book, the proper way to group my folders and to include my files?

EDIT: I would also like to see some tips on actually including the files. What are some techniques to include a file, no matter where include() is called? A specific example, according to my first structure.

There was a script in `includes/scripts`, `login.php`. `login.php` then included `page.php` (a simple page template) from `includes/`. `page.php` would include several parts of the template (`header.php`, `footer.php`). But I also had to call `page.php` from the files in `include/`.

This was giving me trouble, because the relative path would be different if `page.php` was called from `includes/` or from `includes/scripts/`

Comment: Sorry if I need to say it, but *by the book* there is no such proper way. If you could say which problems you're specifically fighting with (I read here about the organisation of the .php files between the lines, but which problem?), I think it would make potential answers more helpful for you and other users in a similar situation.

Comment: What you're doing now, i.e. no grouping at all, is the one thing I'd never do. At the very least you should keep script files that aren't meant to be accessed directly from the web somewhere separate so you can block access to them. After that, there are generally two major ways to go about this: "package-by-layer" or "package-by-feature". The former is easier to do unambiguously; the latter requires more thought / work, but I'd argue can lead you to factoring your code better. (E.g. if you can't think which feature a class belong to, it might be good to split it up.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem was probably caused by relative paths.

This can be solved by using absolute paths eg.:

```
require_once("/var/www/clients/client05/web29/web/includes/scripts/myClass.php");
```

To make it easier you can also define constants in `index.php` (or any other file that will get included every time)

```
define("WEB_ROOT", "/var/www/clients/client05/web29/web/");
define("INCLUDES_DIR", WEB_ROOT . "includes/");
define("SCRIPTS_DIR", INCLUDES_DIR . "scripts/");
```

Files can then be easly included

```
    require_once(SCRIPTS_DIR . "myClass.php");
    require_once(INCLUDES_DIR . "acp.php");
```

Comment: Your code won't be portable this way. Use `__DIR__`, and stick with autoloading for classes - explicit requires are just a mess.

Comment: This is probably what I need. The other answers did help, and I will use them. But this answer actually fixed my problem.

Answer (score 1):

A just straight forward suggestion:

```
index.php
app/
styles/
images/
```

All PHP code goes into `app/` and can be further organized like you see fit, for example one directory for your templates, one to store third-party code and then your own library that you build for your application.

You should be able to move the `app` folder then anytime to any other location on disk, especially out of the document root.

This is most easily done with a so called [*front controller*](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/frontController.html) that is routing all request that are incomming to the application to the relevant code (technically this allows you to even have multiple applications side-by-side).

In the layout above, `index.php` plays that role. It's the entry-point to your application.

Answer (score 1):

You should not think about mere *files*, but about *strategies* about how to interact with *resources*.

As PHP has nice object oriented support now, you may take advantage of [namespaces](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php), and organize your classes in folders, the way you like.

If you don't want to use a framework [thing I strongly advise you to do however, as it will make your app secure and more maintainable], you will find [this article](http://fabien.potencier.org/article/50/create-your-own-framework-on-top-of-the-symfony2-components-part-1) enlightening about how to organize your structure.

You can pick up some components like the **symfony autoloader** to load classes as you wish, then handle all the other resources [css, js, images] simply according to your filesystem organization.

Answer (score 1):

My preferred organizational structure involves:

**index.php** and all other php pages in the root ("/")
**/includes/** (directory for included template items like header, footer, analytics code, etc... anything frequently reused)
**/includes/classes/** (for php classes)
**/images/** (self explanitory; I also use several directories inside this based on the most sensible organization of my images)
**/style/** (for css, with a "/style/fonts/" directory for font files)
**/scripts/** (for js or similar)
**/support/** (for any setup files I might be utilizing)